# Subset and sort a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object by one variable

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, sp, order

I took a sample of a spatial polygon dataframe with 2256 elements using:

```
valdata <- ref_10[sample(ref_10@data$ID, length(ref_10)/3),]
```

now I would like to sort my new spatial dataframe by my ID-colum and always get this error message:

> valdata[sort(valdata@data$ID),]
>
> Error in valdata[sort(valdata@data$ID), ] : cannot get a slot
>   ("Polygons") from an object of type "NULL"

Comment: ID wasn't included, just wrap the sample in sort()

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
valdata<-ref_10[which(ref_10@data$ID %in% sample(ref_10@data$ID, length(ref_10)/3)),]
```